# Find direction of motion on a circular path where start angle and end angle is given from initial position

Tags: trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Consider a clock with only one hand. We consider angle = 0 degree when hand is at 12. Now this hand can freely move in clockwise direction or anticlockwise direction. Given starting angle and ending angle of this clock hand I need to figure out direction of rotation.

I have centre of circle and I can create direction vectors using that. For example, if start angle is 0 and end angle is 90 degree then by using cross product of initial vector and final vector I can determine direction, But, problem with this solution is that it does not work for angles >180 degrees. Also it doesn't handle cases where hand was initially at 11 and then on 1 or vice versa.

Is there a reliable way of finding out direction of rotation with given information?

Comment: The direction is not fixed. It could have moved either clockwise or anticlockwise to reach that point.

Comment: Right, what if I also happen to have x,y coordinates of the points on circle?

Comment: oh, its the same thing, Never mind, thanks!